# Cyphons and the persistent confusion of vacuum as a force

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, vacuum

- tldr this is primarily about academic concensus rather than mechanics
- refs to 'vacuum' / 'relative vacuum' might be better described as 'pressure differential'. I defer to the physicists in the room.

First to caveat I'm no physicist, but have always sought to understand the world better.  I once had an extended argument with a friend on the physics of the ciphon.  It seemed to me the force pulling water upwards on the intake side was the greater weight of water on the other - this based on the observation that ciphons start quicker with higher height differentials.  But I figured there must also be some force keeping all water together, and guessed maybe this was a relative vacuum - i.e. roughly equal atmouspheric pressure at both ends of the pipe preventing gaps from appearing between water molecules given that the pipe imposes a closed system.

The intensity of atmouspheric pressure should not be important so long as there is a some pressure, so as to enable a relative vacuum.  The theory is confused by observations that cyphon can also work in a vacuum. In this case the model fails, but (it seems to me) the scenario also opens up the possibility for an alternative mechanism - e.g. molecular cohesion - to work instead.

These aspects are all explored quite nicely in the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siphon#Modern_research_into_the_operation_of_the_siphon and yet it is not clear if there is an established academic concensus, given several recent papers since 2010.  This seems surprising for such a simple and contained physical problem.  Perhaps there is more of a concensus today (Wikipedia is of limited reliability).  Hence I thought it would be interesting to seek views on how settled this issue is in the physics community.  Can anyone add an informed view on this question?

Comment: Is state-of-scientific-concensus not focused enough?  Perhaps whoever closed this would be good enough to elaborate

Answer (score 1):

The water in the syphon is below atmospheric pressure at some points, but it must always be above the vapour pressure of the water. Once the pressure at any point in the water gets below  the equilibrium  vapour pressure at that temperature the water will boil and the syphon will stop working.  In a vacuum the water will boil everywhere until it gets so cold as to freeze.

The statements about tensile strength are correct in some sense.  Water can exist without boiling at a pressure below its vapour pressure, but this is a metastable (non-equilbrium) situation and needs very clean water.  As soon as some dust or other stuff gets in the water it will boil.  This is easily demonstated by the dangeous game of repeatedlly boiling water in a microwave. After a few cycles all the dissolved air can be lost and the water can get above its boiling point without acually boiling.  The addition of coffee granuleswill then cause the water to boil violently and may cause injury.

Comment: Thanks Mike. But I should be clear the question is about the degree of academic concensus, rather than the mechanics per se.  Of course if there is such a concensus then flagging it would be of great interest :)